# Dynamic Table with a horizontal Scrollbar in CSS

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, scrollbar

Working on a homepage I came to the following problem:
I want to display a table - the number of table columns can be chosen with checkboxes. Also, my website should work on a mobile phone, so I put in the correspondingly meta line.

Unfortunately, my website do not work properly as it do not shows my horizontal scrollbar..

PHP Code:

```
echo '<table id="dynamictable">';
                echo '<tr>';
                    foreach($res_category_arr as $columnname)
                    {
                        echo '<th>' . $columnname. '</th>';
                    }
                echo '</tr>';

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    while($data_current_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo '<tr>';
                            foreach($res_category_arr as $tabledata)
                            {
                                echo '<td>' . $data_current_row[$tabledata] . '</td>';
                            }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                }

                echo '</table>';
```

res_category_arr represents an array, which contains the wanted column names.
CSS Code:

```
#dynamictable{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

#dynamictable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

#dynamictable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the ID off the table, and put it on a div **AROUND** the table.

It should do what you're looking for, but you might also want to add a width:100% back to the table as well.

EDIT: Figured I would add a simple working example here.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaGARr?editors=1100#0

```
.scroll {
  overflow-x:auto;
  width:100%;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  min-width:700px;
}
```

If you go below 700px wide, the scrollbar shows up